# How do you link a view into a listing dropdown menu?

Tags: 7, views

here are some screenshots i created a new sort view and i have tried to add it to the field collection list and then selected it in the page with the drop down and it does not display the view. Am i doing this right? I am using D7 and the

I am using the nodequeue module

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMrh8.jpg

Comment: Hi Lex. Welcome to Drupal Answers. We need some more information from you. Please edit your post with the following: tag with what version of Drupal you are using, what you are trying to accomplish in more detail and what issue you ran into with what you tried. I am not sure how you managed to get a view selector in the publishing options. What modules are you using?

Comment: hi @Christia :) i am trying to add functionality to my site so that i can organize the items in a view (events in this example) in whatever order i wish. i have the view displaying the items with the proper order but now when i try and add the view to the view selector for the section of the page.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a view to your page?

Comment: yes, this is how we currently add them. https://i.imgur.com/pG0zhMu.png               But for some reason when i select the New view it doesnt display anything...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not reputable enough to comment so I can only post here as an "answer".  But instead of telling you "how", I'm telling you that it appears you can't do this, not *easily* anyway.

It looks like the options you have available in the node edit form: [image]

are provided by these field settings:
[image]

That screenshot of your field settings shows an error:
`There is data for this field in the database.  The field settings can no longer be changed.` which means you can't add a new value (a view in this case) to those particular settings.

That means you can't do this.  Everytime you click the save button it fails to actually save and displays that error message.

There are some options:

1. Edit the database directly -- it's dangerous, don't do it on your live site, only do it on a copy/clone of your site until you're sure it works without breaking things horribly, and you probably shouldn't try this at all.
2. Create a new field with the settings you want.  Then migrate all the data from the old field to the new field.  Delete the old field once the new one is in use and working.  This also should be tested safely on a breakable copy of your site.

Based on what you've shown in your screenshots, those are two possible solutions and neither of them are very good (the second one is better).

It's possible that there actually is a good solution for you, but you really need to provide more information like like @Christia said.  For example, going on your screenshots alone I don't see how this has anything to do with nodqueue or field_collection modules.  This "Listings" functionality in the vertical tabs is mysterious, does it use [dgo.to/viewfield](http://dgo.to/viewfield) or [dgo.to/viewreference](http://dgo.to/viewreference) or some other module?